# getting data by maximum witheffect date

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table named table1 where datas are entered as below.

slno `scxid` exid `cv`  `witheffectdate

2007   `213`35`5000`2012-03-01 00:00:00.000`

2008   `214`35`1000`2012-03-01 00:00:00.000`

2009 `215`35`500`2012-03-01 00:00:00.000`

2010 `213`35`7000`2012-04-01 00:00:00.000`

2011 `214`35`1500`2012-04-01 00:00:00.000`

2012 `215`35`700`2012-04-01 00:00:00.000`

I need to only display the data of exid=35 with maximum witheffectdate only. That is here display only datas from slno 2010 to 2012.
Please helpme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select slno, scxid, exid, cv,  max(witheffectdate) 
from table1
where exid=35
```